# What is wrong with submitting this multi-select?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to submit this multi select as an array but when I submit it nothing prints to the screen so what am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
  <div class="container">  
    <select name="itemsToChoose" id="left" size="8" multiple="multiple">      
      <option value="1">item1</option>  
      <option value="2">item2</option>  
      <option value="3">item3</option>  
      <option value="4">item4</option>  
      <option value="5">item5</option>  
    </select>  
  </div>  

  <div class="low container">  
    <input name="left2right" value="add" type="button">  
    <input name="right2left" value="remove" type="button">  
  </div>  


  <form  Method ="POST" action="multiSelectRead.php">


  <div class="container">  
    <select name="itemsToAdd" id="right" size="8" multiple="multiple">  
    </select>  
  </div>  

  <input type="submit" style="width: 75px; border: 1px solid gray" value="Submit">
<br />

         </form>
```

The JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".low input[type='button']").click(function() {
        var arr = $(this).attr("name").split("2");
        var from = arr[0];
        var to = arr[1];
        $("#" + from + " option:selected").each(function() {
            $("#" + to).append($(this).clone());
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
})



$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#seldist option').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

multiSelectRead.php

```
<?php

print_r($_POST["itemsToAdd"]);



?>
```

The user is suppose to add values then hit submit. But I tried it and yet it wont pass the itemstoAdd values in array to php....

Here is snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/an4gA/

Comment: There is nothing to select in `itemsToAdd`, try adding some options (like you already did for `itemsToChoose`)

Comment: There's no options in `itemsToAdd`, only in `itemsToChoose` above, which seems to be outside of your form.

Comment: looks like there is no option/value provide

Comment: Do you have any code attached to the add and remove buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jsFiddle you posted, your jQuery code to select the options reads:

```
$('#seldist option').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Thing is, your select box's ID is "right".

Either change the `#seldist` above to `#right`, or change your select box's ID to "seldist".

Answer (score 0):

You must make the form element's name into an array with `[]`:

```
<select name="itemsToChoose[]" id="left" size="8" multiple="multiple">
<select name="itemsToAdd[]" id="right" size="8" multiple="multiple">
```

Secondly, in your form you use `itemsToChoose`, which has options, and in your PHP you call `itemsToAdd` which has no options to select.

**UPDATE**

I see an errant space in the form's `method` attribute.  This is causing an empty `$_POST`, but probably not an empty `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`.

```
<form  Method ="POST" action="multiSelectRead.php">
             ^^^^

<form  method="POST" action="multiSelectRead.php">
```

Comment: the user adds options by using Add buttons so options from options to choose get added to itemtoAdd and then the user hits submit which should POST all the values in array from itemstoadd..The user should add options before submitting http://jsfiddle.net/an4gA/

Comment: @Nadal Still if you expect PHP to receive an array of multi-selected options, the name attributes must end in `[]`

Comment: okay I got that but now why isnt that multi select passing its itemstoAdd fields in array to the php

Comment: @Nadal show the whole `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: when i do print_r($_POST); it says Array()  look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/an4gA/ the user adds options from 1 menu to other then submits..

Comment: @Nadal The form's method attribute is messed up. See my update above.

Comment: I did try removing that space michael it did not fix it...

Comment: @Nadal In my tests, that space is the difference between an empty and populated `$_POST`.

Comment: the problem was JQUERY's variable, my multi select's id didnt match the id I was choosing in JQuery. one was "right" the other was "seldiest"

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your select. No values at all.

All values in a select in your code snippet are in `itemsToChoose` and that one is not within your `<form>` tags.

Do a `print_r($_POST);` to see what is submitted and try again.

Also try moving the `<form>` starting tag to include the `itemsToChoose`.

edit: As Michael pointed out, you should make it an array by adding `[]` to the select name